# JavaScript - When will Array comprehension be available for Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, list-comprehension

I think there's nothing else to clarify. I'm looking for array comprehensions in Google Chrome 51.0.2704.84.

When I run this

```
var doubled = [for (i of numbers) i * 2];
```

in the browser console it throws a SyntaxError:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

What reasons would the Chromium team have to not include this feature?

Comment: Array comprehensions are [non-standard and unlikely to be included in the standard any time in the near future.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions) At one point it seemed like they might so a couple of browser engines tried implementing a version of it but don't expect to use it globally.

Comment: thanks, kenbellows, I'm Cuban and it's hard to me to try explain things.

Answer (score 2):

Array comprehension [was included in ECMAScript 6 but later removed.](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions#Browser_compatibility)

The suggested way to implement this behavior is to use the currently available standard array functions like `map` and `filter`.